# PostgreSQL reuse update calculation

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, query-optimization

I have a table for tracking a user's progress in a game, that looks something like:

```
create table progressions (
  user_id       int,
  attempt_count int,
  correct_count int,
  accuracy      float,
  state         text
);
```

I want to create a query that will update a user's progress in the following ways:

- Add a certain number of attempts
- Add a certain number of corrects
- Recompute the accuracy (as a decaying average)
- Recompute the state (based on the new accuracy)

Now, the first 3 points are fairly trivially achieved with something like:

```
update
  progressions p
set
  attempt_count = p.attempt_count + {attempt_count},
  correct_count = p.correct_count + {correct_count},
  accuracy      = p.accuracy * (1 - {alpha}) + ({correct_count} / {attempt_count}::float) * {alpha}
where
  user_id       = {user_id};
```

The problem comes when I want to update the state based on accuracy, where I need to reuse the result of the accuracy expression in the condition(s):

```
  ...
  accuracy = {accuracy_expression},
  state    = case
    when {accuracy_expression} > 0.9 then 'exceptional'
    when {accuracy_expression} > 0.8 then 'pretty good'
    ...
  end
  ...
```

I think I could use a CTE in this situation (with possible atomicity implications), but I'm wondering if there is any other way for me to reuse the result of the accuracy expression without recomputing it?

If not, is this something PostgreSQL would optimise internally if I did repeat it `N` times?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered maintaining these calculated fields with before update triggers instead?

```
create function progressions_accuracy_upd() returns trigger as $$
begin
  new.state := case
    when new.accuracy > 0.9 then 'exceptional'
    when new.accuracy > 0.8 then 'pretty good'
    …
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger progressions_accuracy_upd before update on progressions
for each row when (new.accuracy is distinct from old.accuracy)
execute procedure progressions_accuracy_upd();
```

And, for that matter, have you considered calculating the state field directly in your app? (The accuracy field makes more sense, so as to query for players whose accuracy is between x and y, but state seems like needlessly storing as many strings as there are rows.)